# fromJSON() method parses null data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have created one model like this :

```
class SalesRepResponse {
  bool errors;
  List<Data> data;
  int statusCode;

  SalesRepResponse({this.errors, this.data, this.statusCode});

  SalesRepResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    errors = json['errors'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    statusCode = json['status_code'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['errors'] = this.errors;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['status_code'] = this.statusCode;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int id;
  String displayName;

  Data({this.id, this.displayName});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    displayName = json['display_name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['display_name'] = this.displayName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And i get the same response from API also and i parse data like this :

```
var result = SalesRepResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response1.body));
```

But it stores all the value in SalesRepResponse/Data class as null.

Someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

you have to specify the data in your json like this

```
var result = SalesRepResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response1.body['data/etc']));
```

mean that u have to specify the data which have data for SalesRepResponse by checking your json response

Comment: We can not pass string as parameter inside an array.